How to Assign Multiple Values to a Single Key in a Terraform Map Variable
I am working with Terraform and have defined a variable of map type as shown below:
variable "original_map" {
  type = map(string)
}

original_map = {
  key1 = "value1"
  key2 = "value2"
}

Now, I want to assign two values to the first key (key1). Ideally, I want the map to look like this:
original_map = {
  key1 = ["value1", "value2"]
  key2 = "value2"
}

However, I'm not sure how to achieve this .Thanks for your help

When you say "now I want to assign two values to the first key"  do you mean during run time? Or do you mean the requirements have now changed and the var should always have key1 as a list of strings and key to as a single string?

you don't want/cannot change the type of the variable, is that the case?
